# Flow required module not found for my own module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, static-analysis, typechecking, flowtype

I try to use Flow to do type checking for my existing ES6 code base. I am completely new to Flow, so I followed get started doc [here](https://flowtype.org/docs/type-annotations.html#_).

I ignored all third party modules so they are not type checked.

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
```

But the problem is all import statement referring to my own module report a Flow check error:

[image: Flow check error]

**How do I make Flow recognize modules in my own code base?**

Comment: does denormalizer have a `default` export?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, it has, the code works before adding flow, so it is not the export has issue. could it be that I need to tell flow where is the reference root from .flowconfig file ?

Comment: I don't know anything about flow sorry. I know a bit about modules so I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *module.name_mapper* [.flowconfig option](https://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html#options).

I have the following code in one of my projects:

```
[ignore]
...
[include]
...
[libs]
...
[options]
module.name_mapper='app' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src'
```

And a package.json in my `src/` folder:

```
{
    "name": "app"
}
```

So I can use:

```
import Whatever from 'app/path/to/my/module';
```